# Saving multiple return values from a Python function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, csv, return

I have a function that **returns 4 values** after doing some calculations. **I give as input 5 parameters.**

I run the above function **6 times using 6 different input parameters** to obtain 6 different outputs.

```
def id_match(zcosmo,zphot,zmin,zmax,mlim):
    data_zcosmo_lastz = zcosmo[(data_m200>mlim)*(zcosmo>zmin)*(zcosmo<zmax)]
    data_zphot_lastz = zphot[(data_m200>mlim)*(zphot>zmin)*(zphot<zmax)]
    halo_id_zcosmo = data_halo_id[(data_m200>mlim)*(zcosmo>zmin)*(zcosmo<zmax)]
    halo_id_zphot = data_halo_id[(data_m200>mlim)*(zphot>zmin)*(zphot<zmax)]
    idrep_zcosmo = data_idrep[(data_m200>mlim)*(zcosmo>zmin)*(zcosmo<zmax)]
    idrep_zphot = data_idrep[(data_m200>mlim)*(zphot>zmin)*(zphot<zmax)]

    file2freq1 = Counter(zip(halo_id_zcosmo,idrep_zcosmo))
    file2freq2 = Counter(zip(halo_id_zphot,idrep_zphot))


    set_a = len(set(file2freq1) & set(file2freq2)) # this has the number of common objects

    difference = 100.0 - (set_a*100.0)/len(data_zcosmo_lastz)

    print difference

    return (len(data_zcosmo_lastz),len(data_zphot_lastz),set_a,difference)    

zmin_limits = [0.1,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.3,1.6]
zmax_limits = [0.4,0.7,1.0,1.3,1.6,2.1]
mlim_limits = [5e13,5e13,5e13,5e13,5e13,5e13]

for a,b,c in zip(zmin_limits,zmax_limits,mlim_limits):
    id_match(data_zcosmo_lastz,data_zphot_lastz,a,b,c)
```

The above code prints the `difference` for each of the 6 different input parameters.

**But I would like to know how I can save the output from the function into an array so that I can save it as a `csv file`???**

I know that by doing

`a,b,c,d = id_match(input params)`

will give `a,b,c,d` to have one of the outputs of `id_match`. But I want to store all the return values inside a single array.

Comment: `info = id_match(...)` `mycsv.writerow(info)`

Comment: @zondo could you explain further?

Comment: `id_match()` already returns a tuple.  You can just assign a variable to what it returns and use the `csv.DictWriter.writerow()` method to write it to a file.

Comment: @zondo That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @zondo: Perfect!! You can add that as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: I just did it by recommendation of chepner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id_match()` already returns a tuple.  You don't need to convert it to anything because `csv.DictWriter.writerow()` can handle a tuple.  All you need to do is assign a variable to what `id_match()` returns and write to a `csv` file:

```
with open(myfilename, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile)
    for a,b,c in zip(zmin_limits,zmax_limits,mlim_limits):
        info = id_match(data_zcosmo_lastz,data_zphot_lastz,a,b,c)
        writer.writerow(info)
```

Comment: actually since my for loop has 6 inputs, I had to create an empty info array, i.e. `info = []` and then do `info.append(id_match(input params))`

Comment: otherwise, `info` only had the information of the last input in the `for loop`.

Comment: I posted my answer too hastily and didn't do it quite right.  See my edit.